# Is it possible to pass table parameter without specifying type?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

ADO.NET `SqlCommand` class has [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets(v=vs.110).aspx) `WriteToServer` for performing bulk inserts.

Unfortunately, there's no way to get back values of generated columns. (tell me if I'm wrong).

Have an idea to use `insert into` with `output`.

```
insert into MyTable(Column1,Column2,...)
output iserted.GeneratedColumn1, GeneratedColumn2, ...
select Column1,Column2,....
from @rows
```

where `@rows` should be table-valued parameter. But for both query and SP table-valued parameter must have a type.
 
Thus I need to create a type for each inserted entity.
While it is possible to generate types at the very start of the application there may be a trick (I'm unaware of) to tell the server to 'discover' type while processing the query like it does when makes bulk inserts in concrete table.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Passing a TVP requires a table type defined on the server.  Another option to accomplish the task is by passing the rows as XML, and then using INSERT...OUTPUT...SELECT.  This probably won't perform as well as a TVP but avoids the need for the server-side type definition and might provide good enough performance.

For example, given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.table1
    (
      col1 int IDENTITY ,
      col2 date ,
      col3 varchar(10)
    );
```

the following would do the job.  The xml can be passed as a parameter instead of the variable as in this example.

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '
<rows> 
    <row>
        <col2>2014-01-03</col2>
        <col3>test1</col3> 
    </row>
    <row>
        <col2>2014-10-20</col2>
        <col3>test2</col3> 
    </row>
</rows>';

INSERT  INTO dbo.table1
        ( col2 ,
          col3
        )
OUTPUT  inserted.col1 ,
        inserted.col2 ,
        inserted.col3
        SELECT  rows.row.value('./col2[1]', 'date') AS PaymentDate ,
                rows.row.value('./col3[1]', 'varchar(32)') AS PaidBy
        FROM    @xml.nodes('/rows/row') AS rows ( row );
```

Comment: Good idea, need to test. Thanks

Comment: The only problem with this approach is the need for correct serialization of different values: dates, numbers and so on. It's also possible to generate insert values statement.

Comment: @voroninp, you are correct that values should be serialized according XML data type formatting rules.